# How to remove part of the column name?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with several columns like:

```
'clientes_enderecos.CEP', 'tabela_clientes.RENDA','tabela_produtos.cod_ramo',  'tabela_qar.chave', etc
```

I want to change the name of the columns and remove all the text neighbord a dot.

I only know the method `pandas.rename({'A':'a','B':'b'})`

But to name them as they are now I used:

```
df_tabela_clientes.columns = ["tabela_clientes." + str(col) for col in df_tabela_clientes.columns]
```

How could I reverse the process?

Comment: _remove all the text neighbord a dot._ is not clear. Given the sample columns, post the expected output.

Comment: try using regex to strip the pattern that matches   .*

Answer (score 1):

Try rename with lambda and string manipulation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['clientes_enderecos.CEP', 'tabela_clientes.RENDA','tabela_produtos.cod_ramo',  'tabela_qar.chave'])
print(df)

#Empty DataFrame
#Columns: [clientes_enderecos.CEP, tabela_clientes.RENDA, tabela_produtos.cod_ramo, #tabela_qar.chave]
#Index: []

dfc = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('.')[-1])
print(dfc)

#Empty DataFrame
#Columns: [CEP, RENDA, cod_ramo, chave]
#Index: []
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of whats to the right of the dot you can split the columns names and choose whichever side of the dot you want.

```py
import pandas as pd
df =  pd.DataFrame(columns=['clientes_enderecos.CEP', 'tabela_clientes.RENDA','tabela_produtos.cod_ramo',  'tabela_qar.chave'])
df.columns = [name.split('.')[0] for name in df.columns] # 0: before the dot | 1:after the dot
```